# Capture Video in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I used the following code to record video.

```
    UIImagePickerController *m_objpicker;=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    m_objpicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;           

    m_objpicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];

    // hide the camera controls
    //picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
    m_objpicker.delegate = self;
    //picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
    m_objpicker.allowsEditing=NO;
    // and put our overlay view in
    //picker.cameraOverlayView=m_objOverlayView;
    [self presentModalViewController:m_objpicker animated:YES];
```

When we finish recording

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    NSURL *m_objMediaURL=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    [m_objpicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

My doubt is, how to save the captured video to a location we specify. Also how to use 
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum .

What all things i need to change in my code so that i can save video to a specified location

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to save to the Camera Roll photos/videos album on the phone:

Definition:

```
void UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   NSString *videoPath,
   id completionTarget,
   SEL completionSelector,
   void *contextInfo
);
```

Where and how to execute it:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{

.... code here .....

NSString* m_objMediaURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

//remember to test that the video is compatible for saving to the photos album

UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(m_objMediaURL, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

.... code here .....

}
```

There is no control beyond saving this to the Camera Roll re: location unless you want to save to the application bundle which I do not recommend.

Comment: Please flag this as the correct answer: this place is give and take.

Answer (score 0):

You can save video to a location that you specify, please check following link [how to capture video in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276351/how-to-capture-video-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

To the Save the Video in Photo Album:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 

NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

            if (_newMedia){
                        if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
                              {
                                // Copy it to the camera roll.
                                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), (__bridge void *)(tempFilePath));
                                 }
                         }


-(void) video: (NSString *) videoPath
 didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error
  contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {


NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
```

}